# #WPF ToastNotifications returning 2 exceptions

Tags: sql-server, wpf, toast, sqldependency

I am using ToastNotifcations to handle updates coming from my DB through the Service Broker.

**Usings:**

```
using TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.Enums;
using ToastNotifications;
using TableDependency.SqlClient;
using ToastNotifications.Lifetime;
using ToastNotifications.Messages;
using ToastNotifications.Position;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
```

**Code:**

```
private void _dependency_OnChanged(object sender, TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.RecordChangedEventArgs<Aircraft> e)
        {
            Notifier notifier = new Notifier(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.PositionProvider = new WindowPositionProvider(
                    parentWindow: Application.Current.MainWindow,
                    corner: Corner.BottomRight,
                    offsetX: 10,
                    offsetY: 10);

                cfg.LifetimeSupervisor = new TimeAndCountBasedLifetimeSupervisor(
                    notificationLifetime: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                    maximumNotificationCount: MaximumNotificationCount.FromCount(5));

                cfg.Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            });

            if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
            {
                switch (e.ChangeType)
                {
                    case ChangeType.Update:
                        e.Entity.ToString();

                        Console.WriteLine(e.Entity.ACStatus.ToString());
                                             
                        notifier.ShowWarning("I AM WORKING");
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void Notify_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _dependency.Stop();
        }
```

Through the Console.WriteLine I am getting my good result, however, the `notifier.ShowWarning` is going to the following exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The title missing a "t"

Comment: This is  not how you read exceptions. You always want to know the line where it is thrown and the exception message. The message will very likely tell what's wrong or at least give you a clue. Run your applicatio in debug mode and let the debugger halt. It will allow you to inspect the exception. Go to the main menu and open the Debug menu and select Exception settings. Make sure all exception are checked (at least the CLR exceptions). Then run the debugger.

Comment: Well, after few hours, I found that the exception was thrown at the line of the Toast notifier ```notifier.ShowWarning("I AM WORKING");```, it needs a dispatcher to be launched. Here is the correction:
```this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                     notifier.ShowSuccess($"AC: {e.Entity.XXX.ToString()} Status Changed to {e.Entity.YYY.ToString()}.", options);
                    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);```